# Implementing Binary Search

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Integer;

class sort {
    public void find(int val, int a[], int n) {
        int mid = n / 2;
        System.out.println("the mid value is:" + a[mid]);
        if (a[mid] == val) {
            System.out.println("found " + a[mid] + " in position " + mid);
        } else if (a[mid] < val) {
            for (int i = mid; i < n; i++) {
                if (a[mid] == val) {
                    System.out.println("found" + val);
                }
            }
        } else if (a[mid] > val) {
            for (int i =0; i < mid; i++) {
                if (a[mid] == val) {
                    System.out.println("found" + val);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        int temp;
        int a[] = new int[100];
        System.out.println("enter the nos of elements");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        for (int i =0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        }
        for (int i =0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[j];
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i =0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("enter the value to be searched");
        int val = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        sort s = new sort();
        s.find(val, a, n);
    }
}
```

With the above code I want to find the user-defined value, from the existing array list using binary search. It checks only for middle value and not for the higher or lower value.

I think the loop doesn't works properly.

Kindly find a solution for this.

Comment: @True Soft, It's partially a binary search, but yes, it's not a binary search.  I am not sure if @mano is ready for recursion yet.

Answer (score 4):

Your two inner loops:

```
for(int i=mid;i<n;i++) 
    {
     if (a[mid] ==val)
     System.out.println("found"+val); 
}



    for(int i=0;i<mid;i++)
{
 if (  a[mid] ==val)
     System.out.println("found"+val);
    }
```

Notice that you are accessing `a[mid]`.  `mid` does not change throughout the loop; you meant to use `a[i]`.  Try replacing `mid` with `i`.

Also, you may want to look into indenting your code.  What editor are you using to write your code?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your find() function as below to recursively find the value under search which can be actually called as binary search -

```
  public void find(int val, int a[], int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if(endIndex-startIndex == 1) {
       System.out.println("Not found");
       return;
    }
    int mid = startIndex + ((endIndex-startIndex) / 2);
    System.out.println("the mid value is:" + a[mid]);
    if (a[mid] == val) {
      System.out.println("found " + a[mid] + " in position " + mid);
    } else {
      if(a[mid] > val) {
        find(val, a, startIndex, mid);
      } else {
        find(val, a, mid, endIndex);
      }
    }
  }
```

You may call the function as with startIndex as zero and endIndex as length of array minus one.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest to check the extreme positions values before calling again the search on the partition defined by those positions?